# regex remove all numbers except for the ones combined with alphabets

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to remove numbers from this String, numbers which are not appended with alphabetic characters

This is the String:

> `161072` , OLD RECTORY HOLYWELL HILL ST ALBANS AL1 1BY ,
>       `161408` , HOLYWELL HILL ST ALBANS AL1 1BT , `162589` , PINETOP BIRKLANDS LANE ST ALBANS AL1 1EE

I want to remove `161072`, `161408`and `162589`. I want this output:

> OLD RECTORY HOLYWELL HILL ST ALBANS AL1 1BY ,
>         HOLYWELL HILL ST ALBANS AL1 1BT , PINETOP BIRKLANDS LANE ST ALBANS AL1 1EE

Remove:  **161072**

Don't remove the '1s' from: **AL1 1BT**

If I use `\\d` then all the numbers are removed:

```
myString= myString.replaceAll("\\d", "");
System.out.print(myString);
```

Any help ? I tried to search for a similar question but I couldn't find any. Please let me know if my question is not clear or if its a duplicate. Thanks

**EDIT**

It would be nice to have a behavior where the regex doesn't remove number (if only its a single number) right after the word:

> Don't remove    word(space)number

example: Street 1

Comment: There is no requirement to keep numbers after specific strings in the question. Tushar's answer is a valid one to match and remove *numbers which are not appended with alphabetic characters*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry my bad, I've edited my question. It would be nice to get the other requirement as well but its not a show stopper.

Comment: The update requirement is very unclear. Should this number be the last in the string? "A single number" means a "single digit", doesn't it? Or should there be a list of words after which a "number" (digit(s)) should be kept?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes you're right, it would really be confusing, since I want large numbers to be removed a street could be like Street 456. Now I'm confused. But I've accepted Thushar's answer for my first problem though.

Comment: Please think of the requirements for the edge cases, and then, if you fail to adapt this one, you can post a new question.

Comment: You know how managers are right? I was told only to remove numbers in a scenario which Tushar solved, but what if later on he says don't remove the numbers for like "street 1" I was hoping to avoid another question, because if its already answered then it would be a duplicate hence no contribution to the community.

Comment: "Managers"? SO users, you mean? That is why I wrote: *if you fail to adapt this one*. You should then post exact steps you followed, your attempt, test cases. Well, a question like "How can I remove a number from "Street 1" string?" will be downvoted, closed and deleted, sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) RegEx

```
\b\d+\b
```

This will match one or more digits which are not surrounded by any alphabetical character and `_` underscore.

**Code:**

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("\\b\\d+\\b", "");
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/qI6jU5/1)

Comment: Doesn't this also match for example "Street 2" and remove the 2?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes, that'll remove `2` from `Street 2` but that's what OP's requirement is, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35410271/regex-remove-all-numbers-except-for-the-ones-combined-with-alphabets#comment58521524_35410316)

Comment: @Tushar `[^a-z](\\d+)[^a-z]` this removes alphabets which have a number on their trail. example in **AL1 1EE** it becomes **A1EE**

Comment: @SharpEdge Do you want to keep `2` from `Street 2`? Since `2` here is not appended or prepended by alphabetes, it should be removed as you've said _I'm trying to remove numbers from this String, numbers which are not appended with alphabetic characters_. If yes then please update the question to add such examples. If you just want to remove 6 digit numbers then use `\b\d{6}\b` regex.

Answer (score 3):

Use word boundaries:

```
\\b\\d+\\b
```